# Elemento repetido usando doble foreach. PHP-Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo dos arreglos de objetos y necesito hacer consultas a la DB con información de cada uno de ellos, para eso hago un doble foreach para tomar los valores necesarios. El problema es que cuando agrego un nuevo campo a los dos objetos anteriores para asignarle la consulta de la base de datos, siempre se coloca el mismo (el último en consultar). Acá abajo les dejo el código.

```
            foreach($juegos as $j){
                foreach ($competitors as $comp) {
                    $quinielas = \DB::table('quinielas')
                        ->where('match_id', $j->matchId)
                        ->where('competitor_id', $comp->competitorId)
                        ->where('competitor_group_id', $group)
                        ->select('id', 'gol_a', 'gol_b', 'points', 'correct_a', 'correct_b', 'correct_result', 'win')
                        ->first();

                    $comp->quiniela = $quinielas;
                }
                $j->competitors = $competitors;
            }
```

El objeto quiniela, se repite en cada juego.

Comment: ¿Qúe relación hay entre juegos y competitors?

Comment: ¿Son necesarias tantas consultas a la base de datos? Creería que debe haber una forma de hacer una sola consulta.

Comment: @VíctorMendoza Un competidor crea quinielas del juego.

Comment: @Shaz Quiero armar un objeto que contenga de manera acoplada los datos. de la forma:
Juegos: [
{
    ...,
   competitors:[
{
   ...,
   quiniela: {
   ...
}
}
]
}
]

Comment: Buenas, puedes poner la estructura de las tablas Juegos, competitors y quiniela. Aunque solo sean los campos de las asociaciones entre las tres tablas.